# dual-homed Centos 7 cannot be ping'd or ssh'd from some on LAN, sees ssh connection refused on one subnet

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking

I have 2 subnets, **A** and **B** and a router connected to both **A** and **B** and the WAN.

I have 4 servers dual homed on subnets **A** and B, 2 of them are Mac OS and 2 of them are Centos 7 (1503). They are all configured to reply on the same interface that requests were received and the gateway on the **B** subnet is their default gateway. This [diagram](http://postimg.org/image/zctk4s323/) shows the network.

The 2 Mac OS servers and one of the CentOS servers, **Bob**, work fine in that each can ping and ssh into the others via their subnet **A** or **B** addresses.

Additionally, clients on subnet **A** can also access the Mac OS servers and the CentOS server, **Bob** via their subnet **A** or **B** addresses; and the three servers can access any of the clients on subnet A.

The second CentOS server, **Alice**, is the problem.

None of the other dual-homed servers or clients on subnet **A** can ping or ssh into **Alice** using **Alice**'s subnet **A** address. Pings and ssh simply hang and I see no evidence of traffic at **Alice** via tcpdump. The arp tables on the other servers and clients all show that **Alice**'s IP addresses on subnets **A** and **B** are mapped to the appropriate MAC addresses.

None of the other dual-homed servers can ping or ssh into **Alice** using **Alice**'s subnet **B** address.

However, clients on subnet **A** are able to ping and ssh into **Alice** by using **Alice**'s address on subnet B.

Further, **Alice** can ping and ssh into all servers and clients via subnet A; and can ping the other three servers on subnet B, but when **Alice** attempts to ssh into any of the servers via their subnet **B** addresses, **Alice** receives "Connection refused"?!

The servers **Bob** and **Alice** are intended to be configured the same except of course for addresses.

I've compared the various */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/{ifcfg-, route-, rule-}{eno1, eno2}* on **Bob** and **Alice** and they appear to be identical except for the addresses assigned to each interface.

I've compared "ip addr", "ip route", "ip rule" between **Bob** and **Alice** and all look identical save for address assignments.

I have disabled SELinux and disabled the firewall on **Alice** to remove these from consideration.

I'm befuddled regarding where the misconfiguration on **Alice** is.

It seems to me from the evidence that there is not **A** hardware problem with either of **Alice**'s interfaces since I can reach each interface from the router via the subnet **A** and **B** addresses for **Alice** and clients on subnet **A** can reach **Alice** via the subnet **B** address.

It doesn't seem to be **A** problem in the router since all other combinations of communication are working.

Further, the connection refused doesn't seem to be **A** configuration issue with the other three servers via subnet **B** since they are all able to connect to each other on subnet B. From looking at tcpdump when **Alice** tries to connect to the other three servers on subnet B, I don't see any packets arriving at the **B** interfaces on the other three servers.

I would really appreciate any ideas about where to probe to try and resolve this issue.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: i would look at arp tables (mac addresses) and work your way up the networking stack.... take a look at the switchport alice's interface B is plugged into, and ensure its the right vlan config. tcpdump is you friend, and it sounds like you on the right track using it

Comment: The arp tables look correct on Alice and all other systems. There are no vlans involved. Since I can ping Alice on both subnets from the router and ssh into Alice on both subnets from the WAN through the router and since single-homed clients on subnet **A** can ping and ssh **Alice**'s subnet B address it would appear the switches and **Alice**'s NICs are functioning properly. Also **Alice** can ping and SSH all systems on subnet **A**. Only the systems on subnet **B** give connection refused when **Alice** attempts to SSH. Ping works fine in that situation.

Comment: so alice can ping hosts on subnet B, but ssh gets rejected on subnetB hosts?  firewalling tcp/22 or sshd not running on subnetB hosts? post your routing table on alice as well.....  it may be traffic to subnet B is going out interface A?  use tcpdump to check this. run tcpdump on the router and on alice and the subnetB hosts while pinging to understand further

Comment: The first thing to do is to consider one of the problematic scenarios and figure out what sequence of packets the various hosts would have to be sending when it is working correctly. Then you need to look at the actual traffic using tcpdump or similar and identify the first point at which it differs.

Answer (score 0):

After some wireshark captures with quite a few ICMP redirects from the router to the "hidden" server, I traced the problem to an overly zealous use of policy routing rules. Once the rules were simplified the problem was resolved.